# Vertically align buttons in a list of items

Tags: html, css

How can I get the buttons in a list aligned with each other vertically?  I thought `display:table-cell` would work but must be missing something.

```css
li {
  display: table;
  }

span {
  display: table-cell;
  }

.left {
  text-align: left;
  }

.right {
  text-align: right;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="left">color: blue</span> 
    <span class="right"><button type="button">Click</button><span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="left">Property Type: Value</span>
    <span class="right"><button type="button">Click</button><span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="left">true: false</span>
    <span class="right"><button type="button">Click</button><span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `width` to `.left`.

```css
li {
  display: table;
}
span {
  display: table-cell;
}
.left {
  text-align: left;
  width: 120px;
}
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="left">color: blue</span> 
    <span class="right"><button type="button">Click</button><span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="left">Property Type: Value</span>
    <span class="right"><button type="button">Click</button><span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="left">true: false</span>
    <span class="right"><button type="button">Click</button><span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't used `display:table` much!

Answer (score 2):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/geqc4b3c/

For your specific purpose, you are missing `table-row`.

This will do the job, and with dynamic width, so you don't need to have a fixed width:

```
ul {
    display: table;
}
li {
    display: table-row;
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
}
.left {
    text-align: left;
}
.right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

This follows the logical structure of a table: `table->rows->cells`

Answer (score 1):

You might read into the css attribute `float`. In your case `float: right` might be appropriate.
Good luck!

Comment: I was thinking float could do it, but I'm pretty familiar with that one.  I don't often use `display:table` so I was not sure what was the issue.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `width` and by the way: close your `<span>` tag (the one that wraps the `button` element):

http://jsfiddle.net/2kyo9jq8/

PS: Run code snippet is not good in this case. It's better a fiddle so one can play around with it to find the bug.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I was not aware that I had to add a width, or that I missed the closing tag in the span.